# Regulation and balancing of readymade packed mayonnaise and other sauces

Tags: sauce, storage-lifetime, acidity, mayonnaise

How to reduce the acidity of packet sauces and mayonnaises? I came to know these packed food stuffs are very acidic to prevent any bacterial attack and i felt it my own, so what is the best way to reduce its acidity if it is suppose to use in a single day we open the packet? So that I can avoid the overhead of making sauces and mayonnaise of my own by using the best brand packets available in the market.

Comment: Are you talking about percived acidity or meassured ph?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, being able to use good quality processed mayonaise would be nice....well, calcium regulates acidity. I have experimented with this using dairy, and it does help a bit. I never went as far as adding pure calcium, but that would probaby work better and have less impact of the taste of, say, mayonaise. It makes sauces feel and look more creamy too, and apparently this works with pure calcium as well:

http://www.foodmanufacturing.com/news/2014/04/adjusting-calcium-acidity-levels-may-improve-dressings-and-sauces